# Install tkinter on centos 6.5 with python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, centos, virtualenv

I want to install tkinter on a Centos 6.5 with python 3.5. I am using a virtual env. I have already installed python-tk, python-imaging-tk, python3-tk and tkinter via yum. However, when I try

> import tkinter

I get

> ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I you are willing to settle for Python 3.4 then you can run

```
yum install -y epel-release
yum install -y python34-tkinter
```

This also install the `python3.4` binary and then you can run

```
import tkinter
```

If you instead need Python 3.5, then you probably need to build it from source which is a bit cumbersome.